# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python-3.x, centos, setup.py

I cannot deal with _ctypes error. If you have an idea, let me know.

## PROBLEM

When I set up my repository on CentOS server, I just want to run

```sh
python3 setup.py develop
```

```
from typing import IO, List

from setuptools import find_packages, setup


def read_req(filename: str) -> List[str]:
    f: IO
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()


def main() -> None:
    req = read_req("requirements.txt")
    mysql = read_req("mysql_requirements.txt")

    setup(
        name="sample",
        description="sample description",
        version="0.1.0",
        install_requires=req,
        extras_require={"mysql": mysql},
        packages=find_packages(exclude=["repo/notebooks", "repo/modules", "data/"]),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I got following error,

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Although I've execute several ways which is suggested as a solution on the internet, I cannot resolve this.

## Enviroment

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Python 3.7.3
```

## Actions I tried already

```
* yum install libffi-devel
* yum install libffi-devel gcc gcc-c++ zlib zlib-devel readline-devel openssl-devel bzip2-devel sqlite-devel
```

Comment: Post contents of `setup.py` and how you installed python

Comment: Sorry, I cannot remember how I installed python3.7 because I did a long time ago. Should I check what information?

Comment: Does `python3 -c 'import ctypes'` works?

Comment: No. same error was occurred

Comment: I would reinstall python, you can get `python36` package from EPEL, or, you can troubleshoot the `cytpe` problem, it is broken

Comment: Well..., I appreciate your solution. Actually, I also installed python3.6, but my project depends on python3.7+ because I used dataclass. Based on your opinion, I cannot use python3.7 on CentOS so far?

Comment: Yes you can, is just that is easier to install from epel.. look for a file bamed _ctypes.so in your installation, do `ldd _ctypes.so` check if there is any not found